# App Fecha ao instalar quando vou testar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Eu sou um iniciante e já no meu primeiro tutorial eu tenho esse erro

Eu fiz todo o processo como está no tutorial em vídeo, e quando tento testá-lo no meu telefone, ele faz a compilação, instala, abre e fecha o aplicativo.

Eu olhei em todos os lugares, pesquisei aqui e não encontrei nada.

Este é meu logcat.

```js
10-27 14:46:05.342 20653-20653/com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro, PID: 20653
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro/com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
        at com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:13)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
10-27 14:46:08.385 20653-20653/com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20653 SIG: 9
```

Meu MainActivity:

```js
package com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText IdadeCachorro = findViewById(R.id.textoIdadeID);
    private Button BotaoCalcular = findViewById(R.id.botaoCalcularID);
    private TextView Resultado = findViewById(R.id.resultadoID);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BotaoCalcular.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @SuppressLint ( "SetTextI18n" )
            @Override
            public
            void onClick ( View v ) {

                String TextoDigitado = IdadeCachorro.getText().toString();

                if(TextoDigitado.isEmpty()) Resultado.setText("Não digitaste nada babaca");
                else {

                    int IdadeDigitada = Integer.parseInt(TextoDigitado);
                    int ResultadoFinal = IdadeDigitada * 7;

                    Resultado.setText(ResultadoFinal + " Anos");


                }

            }
        } );

    }


}
```

Meu Android Manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Meu MainActivity, Só tem isso no app

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cafbab"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Cont_Descr_Imagem"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.289"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:text="@string/Texto_informativo"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textoIdadeID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textoIdadeID"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:background="#f3fac7"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Hint_Texto_editavel"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/botaoCalcularID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botaoCalcularID"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:text="@string/Texto_botao_calcular"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/resultadoID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textoIdadeID" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultadoID"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/botaoCalcularID" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, o problema foi resolvido

Eu estava com esse problema e me disseram para colocar "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" no meu código, pois estava faltando, porem, não sei quando acabei colocando "Abstract classe" na minha classe, e por isso o "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" não ajudou, depois de muito tentar achei e retirei esse "Abstract classe".

Agora está funcionando. Obrigado a todos

Ps. não sei onde fechar o tópico :)

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre quando, antes mesmo da `Activity` ser criada, vc está atribuindo um valor que ainda não existe dos IDs do layout. Conheça mais sobre o [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=pt-br) do Android.

Altere seu código para:

```
private EditText IdadeCachorro;
private Button BotaoCalcular;
private TextView Resultado;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IdadeCachorro = findViewById(R.id.textoIdadeID);
    BotaoCalcular = findViewById(R.id.botaoCalcularID);
    Resultado = findViewById(R.id.resultadoID);
    //restante do código....
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, o estranho é que se eu criar um novo App e não programar nada ele funciona normal, mas assim que eu programo ele da esse erro

Comment: Eu copiei o seu código e tive o mesmo problema que vc teve, na linha 13 (at com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:13)) Se vc clicar no único link azul, como o seu código estava, vai te indicar erro na inicialização do EditText IdadeCachorro. Colocando o código como está na minha resposta, rodou normalmente. Vc pode inserir o Logcat, para eu analizar?

Comment: Outro detalhe, na convenção de criação de variáveis, a primeira letra deve ser sempre minúscula. Letra maiúscula na primeira letra, apenas para Classes. :)

Comment: Nada, não sei se tem a ver, mas meu logcat não para, fica aparecendo um mensagens entre elas aparece muitas E/. Tipo assim:
 E/SensorService: activeConnections...
D/SensorService: SensorService hasOneShotSensors handle:1 mode:0
E/SensorService: activeConnections...
 D/SensorService: SensorService hasOneShotSensors handle:5 mode:1
 - W/ActivityManager: Skip forceProcessStateUpTo() to newState 8

Comment: Vc pode filtrar o seu logcat, para o pacote do seu projeto. Do lado direito superior da visualização do logcat, vc vai encontrar um combo box, provavelmente estará escrito "No Filters". Selecione o "Edit Filter Configuration", na tela de criação, vc pode modificar o nome do filtro e no campo "Package Name", insira o seu pacote "com.example.imperador.idadedecachorro". Caso tenha dúvidas, veja este [vídeo](https://caster.io/lessons/android-studio-applying-logcat-filters).